# Why would a "user is taken" method that queries a MySQL database pass an immutable dict?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

I am creating a Flask Application that connects to a locally-hosted MySQL database (Using SQL-Alchemy ORM). When a user creates an account, I have a method `is_taken` and returns `True` or `False` depending on if a user with that username already exists.

Here is the method:

```
def is_taken(username):
    q = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    return not (q is None)
```

Although not on a regular basis, the following error occurs at least once a day:

> StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect
>   until invalid transaction is rolled back [SQL: u'SELECT users.uid AS
>   users_uid, users.username AS users_username, users.fullname AS
>   users_fullname, users.password AS users_password, users.score AS
>   users_score, users.totalattempted AS users_totalattempted,
>   users.totalcorrect AS users_totalcorrect, users.settings AS
>   users_settings \nFROM users \nWHERE users.username = %s \n LIMIT
>   %s'] [parameters: [immutabledict({})]]

The error is triggered specifically on:

```
q = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've had a invalid transaction before executing this query. first of all I suggest you to find the problem of previous query that led to this problem. and for fixing this problem you execute `session.rollback()` before running the query.

Comment: So in other words, an invalid transaction would cause the method to return an immutable dict?

Comment: @rawells14 no! the invalid transaction prevents making another transaction by raising an error until you clear the session.